# Image allocation OutOfMemoryError and crash in Android

Tags: android, xml, image

I've a problem with my app relate to OutOfMemoryError and crash. I've realized two activity, first activity with a logo used to load application and a second activity with some buttons and a popup menù with some icons. Recently I've encountered problem with this popup menù that when is opened cause a crash with "OutOfMemoryError" warning. Before this crash I've used this menù without errors with only a single image repeated as test. When I've changed this image with different images it started to crash. I've added this *android:largeHeap="true"*  to manifest too see if something changes and finally menu opens without crash but it lags when scrolling it. In application monitoring I've 112Mb used when menu is closed that goes to 204Mb when I open it. I've 115 images inside my drawable(mostly unused), about 35 active in my current Activity and additional 16 images when I open menu. Total images size is 4Mb, total used images size is 1Mb and total menu images size is 350Kb. I'm a newbie in Android but maybe I skip some conversion between png and memory in Android, but it's strange to me that 16 images(ImageButton) of 24kB with *android:layout_width="85dp" android:layout_height="90dp"* occupy so much memory and makes lag a new age smartphone. With this low sizes and no particular code(just xml files and some java to struct UI), how it's possible that I've this big numbers in my memory?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image files? (Not the dimensions of the imageButtons)

Comment: A single image inside menù have 20.5Kb dimension (24Kb on disk), 455x498px.

Comment: Try not loading the images to see if they are definitely the cause of the problem and if they are, try sizing them down.

Comment: Yes, I've no changes in memory allocated size when no images are loaded. I can scale them down, but I've an HD screen and if I load lower quality images it's visible. I can't understand why 300Kb becomes 100Mb.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't follow android standard size of icons, or the image is too large.

check this link for more info on how to use standard size in android : http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Or you can use Universal Image Loader to display image see this link : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader